# Need help resolving IOexception on FileOutputStream and DataOutputStream

Tags: java

I'm trying to write integers to a text file as a method of saving a game, but I am getting both IOExceptions and a FileNotFound exception (written in comments on the line they occur). The saveData class is storing character stat, which are all ints. What should I do to fix the exceptions?

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    Character player = new Character();

    System.out.print("Enter your username: ");
    String user = s.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Give a name to the file: ");
    String filename = s.nextLine();
    s.close();

    Vector<Integer> saveData = new Vector<Integer>();
    saveData.add(player.Int);
    saveData.add(player.Vit);
    saveData.add(player.Str);
    saveData.add(player.Dex);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\" + user + "\\" + filename + ".csv"); //Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException
    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);

    for(int i = 0; i < saveData.size(); i++) {
        dos.writeInt(saveData.get(i)); //Unhandled exception type IOException
    }

    dos.close(); //Unhandled exception type IOException
```

Comment: `FileOutputStream` throws a `FileNotFoundException`: [_if the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason_](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#FileOutputStream-java.lang.String-)

Comment: The issue isn't that an exception is being thrown, but that your code doesn't attempt to deal with a checked exception. And, unrelated to your issue, `Vector` is long deprecated.

Comment: Agreed with @jsheeran: use *try-with-resource* blocks and handle exceptions. It will be really useful in Java...

Answer (score 0):

if you `user` directory doesn't exist youll get that exception. Should use `user.name` to get the current logged in user name instead of asking for it

try the following:

```
String user = System.getProperty("user.name"); //get the current logged in user name

Path path = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\" + user + "\\" + filename + ".csv");

//Try-with-resource will close DOS even upon exception
try(DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(Files.newOutputStream(path)) {
  for(int i = 0; i < saveData.size(); i++) {
    dos.writeInt(saveData.get(i)); 
  }
} catch (IOException ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  File yourFile =  File yourFile = new File("C:\\Users\\" + user + "\\" + filename + ".csv");
    yourFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
    try (DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(yourFile))) {

        for (int i = 0; i < saveData.size(); i++) {
            dos.writeInt(saveData.get(i));
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: While your solution would work. the user shouldn't be creating folders in the `Users` directory on windows. Instead the username should be taken from `user.name` property. Also `try-with-resource` and `java.nio` should be used for resource management.